# Error en al intentar insertar un registro en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, html5, php7, hosting

les cuento, lo que pasa es que subí mi pagina a un hosting gratuito, y al momento de intentar registrar datos de un formulario en una base de datos MySQL, me lanza el error "Error al intentar registrar en la base de datos" ¿A qué se deberá? no entiendo porque sucede, el código está correcto según yo, e incluso la consola del navegador tampoco me tira algún error, anteriormente me funcionaba sin problemas, pero ahora ya no.

formulario.php

```
<?php  

include 'conexion_be.php';

    $tipo_personal = $_POST['tipo_personal'];
    $tipo_instalacion = $_POST['tipo_instalacion'];
    $planta = $_POST['planta'];
    $puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $tipo_trabajo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
    $nombres = $_POST['trabajador_asignado'];
    $autorizacion = $_POST['autorizacion'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO planificacion_faena(tipo_personal, tipo_instalacion, planta, puesto_trabajo, fecha, tipo_trabajo, ubicacion, trabajador_asignado, autorizacion) VALUES('$tipo_personal', '$tipo_instalacion', '$planta', '$puesto', '$fecha', '$tipo_trabajo', '$ubicacion', '$nombres', '$autorizacion')";

    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    if ($ejecutar) {
        echo '<script>
                alert("Datos ingresados correctamente");
                window.location = "../formulario.php";
        </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script>
        alert("Error, Inténtalo de nuevo");
        window.location = "../formulario.php";
    </script>';
    }


?>
```

Hubo un momento que al subir las tablas hacia la base de datos (del localhost al hosting), tuve que borrarlas y luego re-resubirlas, porque anteriormente me registraba sin ningún problema, pero cuando hice ese proceso ocurrió lo que ya mencioné, ¿Habrá tenido que ver eso? o no?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código real? En el trozo de código que muestras no está el mensaje de error que indicas en la pregunta, por tanto, no podemos ni siquiera ver por dónde está yendo el programa. Por favor, pulsa en [edit]  para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

podrias mostrar el error de mysql al final de la query:

```
$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error($conexion), E_USER_ERROR);
```

Esto te mostrará lo que falla, si quieres nos lo muestras si no lo entiendes y te lo explicamos.

Comment: perdonando la ignorancia en que parte del código debo ponerlo? lo reemplazo por el ejecutar que tengo?

Comment: Hola no te preocupes, si tienes que reemplazarlo

Comment: @nicolasyo1WWE funciona? Estaría bien que respondieras o agradecieras la ayuda y un consejo en vez de abrir un diferentes hilo del mismo asunto estaría bien que fuera en un solo, asi evitas que te cierren